# matrix exponential in cvxpy

Tags: exponential, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to implement the following convex-optimization problem in `cvxpy`:

```
A = a given matrix of dimension dim x dim  
B = a given matrix of dimension dim x dim  
X = cp.variable((dim, dim))  
distance = cp.norm(exp(X)-A, 'fro')  
delta= some positive real value  

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(X-B,'fro'))  
constraint = distance < delta    
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraint)  
prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS)
```

This clearly requires the **implementation of the matrix exponential function** `exp(X) =sum_n (1/n!) X^n` (thus not element-wise!) for a `cvxpy` matrix variable, but I did not find such a function in the documentation.

Has this been implemented, or alternatively is there a way to easily do so?

Comment: Please consider posting at Math SE, which has a [tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvxpy) for CVXPY.